# How is .. (dot dot) resolved in bash when cwd is a symlink to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

Consider the following folder structure:

```
.
├── test1
│   ├── nested1
│   ├── testfile11
│   └── testfile12
└── test2
    ├── nested1 -> /path/to/dir/test1/nested1
    └── testfile21
```

`test2/nested1` is a symlink to the directory `test1/nested1`. I would expect, if it were the cwd, `..` would resolve to `test2`. However, I have noticed this inconsistency:

```
$ cd test2/nested1/
$ ls ..
nested1  testfile11  testfile12
$ cd ..
$ ls
nested1  testfile21
```

`touch` also behaves like `ls`, creating a file in `test1`.

Why does `..` as an argument to `cd` refer to the parent of the symlink, while to (all?) others refers to the parent of the linked dir? Is there some simple way to force it to refer to paths relative to the symlink? I.e. the "opposite" of `readlink`?

```
# fictional command
ls $(linkpath ..)
```

EDIT: Using bash

Comment: See also [Symbolic link recursion - what makes it "reset"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621) for the longer story

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands `cd` and `pwd` have two operational modes.

- -L  logical mode: symlinks are not resolved
- -P physical mode: symlinks are resolved before doing the operation

The important thing to know here is that `cd ..` does not call the syscall `chdir("..")` but rather shortens the `$PWD` variable of the shell and then chdirs to that absolute path.

If you are in physical mode, this is identical to calling `chdir("..")`, but when in logical mode, this is different.

The main problem here: POSIX decided to use the less safe logical mode as default.

If you call `cd -P` instead of just `cd`, then after a `chdir()` operation, the return value from `getcwd()` is put into the shell variable `$PWD` and a following `cd ..` will get you to the directory that is physically above the current directory.

So why is the POSIX default less secure?

If you crossed a symlink in POSIX default mode and do the following:

```
ls ../*.c
cd ..
rm *.c
```

you will probably remove different files than those that have been listed by the `ls` command before.

If you like the safer physical mode, set up the following aliases:

```
alias cd='cd -P'
alias pwd='pwd -P'
```

Since when using more than one option from `-L` and `-P` the last option wins, you still may be able to get the other behavior.

Historical background:

The Bourne Shell and ksh88 did get directory tracking code at the same time.

The Bourne Shell did get the safer physical behavior while ksh88 at the same time did get the less safe logical mode as default and the options `-L` and `-P`. It may be that ksh88 used the csh behavior as reference.

POSIX took the ksh88 behavior without discussing whether this is a good decision.

BTW: some shells are unable to keep track of `$PWD` values that are longer than `PATH_MAX` and drive you crazy when you chdir into a directory with an absolute path longer than `PATH_MAX`. `dash` is such a defective shell.

Comment: Do you know when exactly that was added to Bourne/Korn? I can see it was in ksh88g, not in ksh88d (SVR4). Note `csh` didn't have anything like that. tcsh has something similar (not enabled by default) added in the 90s (`set symlinks = ignore` or `set symlinks = expand` which goes even further and is even more broken)

Comment: In 1988, the `Bourne Shell` did have code to handle `$PWD` but not code to verify it's content using `lstat()`. This code was added on November 1989

Comment: Just verified: `csh` does not have similar code. I was confused by the fact that csh tracks the logical view of the location in a variable `cwd`. This is why my `bsh` had a variable `$CWD` since 1986.

Comment: Regarding ksh88: The code for -L/-P has been in in Summer 1989. Do you have ksh88 source code from different times?

Comment: I have ksh88d from the SVR4 source on archive.org, and the  changelog on Sven Mascheck's site mentions pwd -P (presumably  added in earlier versions) for ksh88g

Comment: My impression is that these options for `cd` have been present in ksh88c already.

Comment: sorry, my bad `ksh88d` from https://archive.org/download/ATTUNIXSystemVRelease4Version2/sysvr4.tar.bz2 did have them indeed, I didn't check properly earlier.

Comment: To the last part of the question, is there a simple way to get the parent of the symlink without `cd` and `pwd`? Something equivalent to: `echo $(cd test2/nested1/; dirname \`pwd -L\`)`

Comment: Oof. It's nice that `pwd` and `cd` have `-L` options, but `mv` doesn't!

Is there a shell that consistently interprets `..` as a logical path? I often have my CWD set to a symlink, because I like keeping repo files and more private data files in separate directories, and thus symlink the repo as a project subdirectory. (i.e. `cd ~/git` `git clone foo` `mkdir -p ~/proj/foo` `cd ~/proj/foo` `ln ../git/foo git` `curl me@foo.net/private.key` `cd git` `./foo ../private.key`.) But I've ended up with weird junk in my repo root directory, and occasionally overwritten files, and this explains why. 

Answer (score 4):

An important paper to read is http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/lexnames where Rob Pike talks about this issue.

You also need to specify your shell, for instance bash tracks it's idea of the current directory and if you say `cd ..` it just cuts off the last component and changes there, rather than actually issuing a `chdir("..")` system call.

Sorry on my phone at the moment, will edit later...

Comment: 5½ years have passed, so I assume you're waiting on hold for a bank.  It's a helpful answer as it is, but I still hope you get a chance to make the edit.

Comment: @MichaelScheper How did you know it was a bank? Sorry I have lost the context, Rob has retired from Google, ... What more information can I help with?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give -p a try, which will follow the physical directory structure without following symbolic links

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html