# zsh/bash: Expand relative paths in command arguments using logical directory structure rules before execution

Tags: bash, zsh, symlink

So I know that `pwd` and `cd` in the shell have a "logical" and "physical" mode (see [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459732) and questions linked from there).

Now, assume I have this symlink:

```
/home/<username>/foo -> /tmp/bar
```

To follow along locally, just do this:

```
mkdir /tmp/bar
ln -s /tmp/bar ~/foo
```

Now, when I start in my `$HOME` and `cd` into `foo`, I get the "logical" path (with default settings) with `pwd`, and can get the "physical" path with `-P`:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ pwd
/home/<username>/foo
$ pwd -P
/tmp/bar
```

Of course, "`..`" always refers to the parent of the "physical" path (my understanding is that it is not even interpreted by the shell, just passed to the command as-is, and some special built-in commands like `cd` interpret it specially to get the "logical" behavior):

```
$ pwd
/home/<username>/foo
$ realpath ..
/tmp
```

What I want is when I'm in `$HOME/foo` (or any of its subdirectories) that any relative paths I use (e.g. `ls -l ../..`) to be interpreted/expanded relative to the "logical" path (it's fine if I have to prefix my command with something).

For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/<username>/foo
$ vi ../something.txt
```

I want this to resolve to `vi /home/<username>/something.txt`.

Is there something easier/shorter than doing the following (or writing a shell function that I can prefix my command with that goes over all arguments and - if they refer to paths - expand them before passing them to the command)?

```
$ pwd
/home/<username>/foo
$ realpath -L $PWD/../something.txt
/home/<username>/something.txt
$ vi $(realpath -L $PWD/../something.txt)
```

Is there something like a "logical path expansion for command line parameters that are relative file paths being done before the shell executes the command"? I'm using `zsh`, but any solutions for `bash` or `zsh` would be fine.

Comment: Not an answer but a paper worth reading on how plan9 approaches the problem  http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/lexnames ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this for Zsh, since that's what I'm using.

---

To get the effect you want with `..` when using `cd`, simply add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
setopt NO_chase_dots NO_chase_links
```

Documentation here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CHASEDOTS

---

For all other cases, instead of `..`, you will need to use the `:h` ("head") expansion modifier:

```
$ pwd
/home/<username>/foo
$ vi $PWD:h/something.txt
```

If you need to reach up more than one level, you can append a number to it (provided you surround the expression with curly braces) or just repeat the `:h`:

```bsh
# These two are equivalent:
$ vi ${PWD:h2}/foo
$ vi $PWD:h:h/foo
```

Documentation here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers

Comment: Thanks, the `:h` is something I can use :) I heard about modifiers in a zsh session with @guckes years ago, but totally forgot to look there.