# How does resolution of .. and . proceed in Linux systems?

Tags: linux, path, resolution

I am reading Sobell's *A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming*, 4e. Early on he talks about the `.` and `..` and says that they are "synonymous with the pathnames" of the working and parent of working directories. My question is about whether I should think about these as synonyms for relative or absolute pathnames. In the end, I think my misunderstanding has to do with not understanding how Linux systems resolve pathnames.

An example: suppose I enter a command like

`cd ..`

Should I think of the shell as doing a substitution of .. for the absolute pathname of the parent of my current working directory? Or does the "resolution" behave differently when I give a relative pathname (as seems to be the case here because I didn't begin my path with a slash /)? To some extent I guess this question can be phrased as "is relative pathnaming a special case of absolute pathnaming in that every relative pathname is substituted for the appropriate absolute path?"

Comment: In case of `cd`: [*How is `..` (dot dot) resolved in bash when cwd is a symlink to a directory*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459732/108618).

Comment: hmm, to me, `..` looks obviously a relative path, just like e.g. `foo.txt` does. Neither can be resolved without context, the current working directory. But, since you ask _"is relative pathnaming a special case of absolute pathnaming"_ and I wonder, what would the difference be? What would be different if it was a special case of the other, vs. if it was _not_ a special case but something completely separate?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering what the shell *does* with a relative path. That is, does it substitute the relative path for an absolute path and then proceed or no? I guess this is all irrelevant from a user's perspective in the end now that I think about it. @ilkkachu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `.` and `..` and says that they are "synonymous with the pathnames" of the working and parent of working directories

This is a simplification. It's true in most cases, but not always. In most cases, if the current directory is `/one/two/three`, then `cd .` is equivalent to `cd /one/two/three/.` which is equivalent to `cd /one/two/three`, and `cd ..` is equivalent to `cd /one/two/three/..` which is equivalent to `cd /one/two`. Similarly, `ls .` is equivalent to `ls /one/two/three` and `ls ..` is equivalent to `ls /one/two`.

The equivalence is not up to the shell. It's part of the kernel job to resolve `.` and `..`. Historically, `.` and `..` were in fact ordinary directory entries and the kernel didn't have any code handling those in path traversal. The only special code for `.` and `..` was that they were automatically created in every directory, and couldn't be modified or removed. Modern systems tend not to store `.` and `..` as directory entries and instead have special handling in their path traversal code.

You can observe that the shell doesn't do `.` and `..` resolution by passing a path to an external command.

```
$ echo ..
..
$ ls ../s*
../somefile ../someotherfile
```

As I wrote above, resolving relative paths is equivalent to specifying an absolute path in most cases, but not all. For example, it's possible to run an application like this:

1. Create directories and files:

   ```
   drwx------  4 root  root 4096 Jan  1 12:00 /some
   drwx------  2 myapp root 4096 Jan  1 12:00 /some/where
   -rwx------  1 myapp root 4096 Jan  1 12:00 /some/where/myfile
   ```
2. As root, change to the directory `/some/where`.
3. Drop privileges to the user `myapp`.
4. The application can access `myfile` and `./myfile`, but not `/some/where/myfile` or `../where/myfile`, since it doesn't have the permission to traverse `/some`.

Note that this is a general limitation of the equivalence between paths to the same file, not just about `.` and `..`.

There is a special case where `..` is handled inside the shell: for the `cd` command only (and related commands such as `pushd`), the shell itself compresses `/dir/..` into nothing. This includes treating e.g. `cd ..` as `cd /one/two` if the current directory is `/one/two/three` according to the shell. This is generally considered friendlier to humans. In particular, `cd foo` followed by `cd ..` gets you back where you started. This makes a difference when symbolic links are involved. If `link` is a symbolic link which is not to a subdirectory in the same directory, then `link/..` is not the current directory: it's the parent directory of the *target* of `link`. This is called “logical” current directory tracking, and you can switch to “physical” current directory tracking (where the shell doesn't do any special handling of `..`) with `cd -P` or by setting a shell option in some shells.

Comment: Some of this went over my head but that which I did understand was very helpful, thank you! That which I don't understand I will return to as I go further into Sobell's book :)

Comment: As `cd` etc. are build-in commands in the shell it's quite obvious that any path handling they do is done in the shell. It's not really a special case for handling of `..` (etc.). But I guess @Gilles know, and the point about "logical" vs. "physical" directory tracking is good to include.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity It _is_ a special case for `..` in the shell. When you run `cd foo` in the shell, this calls the system call `chdir("foo")` with the same string except that the shell first does `..` compression.

Comment: Re "*`cd /one/two/three/..` which is equivalent to `cd /one/two`*" Usually. It's not if `/one/two/three` is a symlink

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about whether I should think about these as synonyms for relative or absolute pathnames

I would suggest to skip this stage and go straight to thinking about these just like any other directory, because that is what they *are* in all manners relevant to you (unless you are a kernel or filesystem-module developer).

Gilles' answer is fine and well, and I see no particular wrong information in it.

That said: it is absolutely possible and useful to view "." and ".." as bog-standard directories. Whatever you do with them in scripts or applications works just like they were directories (and as Gilles says, in some past they actually were).

Most importantly: you have to keep the concept of an *inode* separate from that of a *directory entry* in your head. An inode describes where "something" is stored in the file system (in a quite physical manner, i.e. the very disk blocks). The *directory entry* is a more abstract representation containing a human-readable name, the corresponding inode, attributes, dates and such.

A *directory* itself can be fined like an internally handled file which has some representation for listing those entries (this is simplified of course). The important bit is that the actual *storage* is very separated from where the info about *where* it's stored.

If I type the following, I can see the inodes of those directories (first column):

```
 ~/tmp$ ls -ilaO
total 8
 16326296 drwxr-xr-x    8 me  staff  -  256 Jan 15 14:02 .
  1129613 drwxr-xr-x+ 112 me  staff  - 3584 Jan 19 17:25 ..
 16326815 drwxr-xr-x    2 me  staff  -   64 Jul 27  2020 a_directory
126333718 -rw-r--r--    1 me  staff  -    0 Jan 15 14:07 a_file
```

Going "upstairs", I can check how `tmp` is represented in its parent directory:

```
 ~$ ls -ilaO -d tmp
16326296 drwxr-xr-x  8 me  staff  - 256 Jan 15 14:02 tmp
```

`tmp` in the parent directory points to the same inode as `.` inside `tmp`, as expected.

Checking the `.` of the parent directory:

```
 ~$ ls -ilaO -d .
1129613 drwxr-xr-x+ 112 me  staff  - 3584 Jan 19 17:25 .
```

reveals that the inode of `.` in the parent is the same as the inode of the `..` entry in the child directory, as expected.

I can use `.` and `..` in almost all places where I could use the name of every other directory in the system. If there is a difference at all, this is because the command I am using has special logic implemented for some reason (for example for security reasons - a web server could enforce that a path can never contain `..` so someone cannot "escape" a security rule and type in an URL like http://domain/index.html/../../../../etc/passwd to get the password file).

Other programs (like `bash`) might have some kind of magic handle ".." special. For example, when I do a `cd ..` the bash knows that my current path is not `/where/i/was/before/..` but just `/where/i/was`. This answers your question about how to think about the shell: you can imagine that it just does what it thinks you want to achieve, to make it easier for you. Other programs which have no special logic for `..` can usually and easily work with `..` anywhere in their paths, and will be blithely unaware of them - everything will just work fine since `..` *is* a path name just like any other path name.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of `.` and `..` happens in kernel. The kernel initializes dnode entries as you descend through a path. The current directory dnode entry has a pointer to its parent directory dnode entry.

It can be observed that the filesystem code is not in play here. If you corrupt a directory's `..` entry to refer to somewhere else, the only way to actually see this is via a handcrafted NFSv2 client. This is so much true that if you corrupt a filesystem so that there are two paths to a directory, `..` still works correctly and you will descend back down the path you came in on.

Some shells handle `cd ..` specially by pealing the last component off the path as text, which results in different behavior when the current directory path is a symbolic link. The shell doesn't know which arguments are filename arguments, and `..` is not a glob pattern; this can easily be seen by doing `echo ..` and observing what comes back.

Source: I developed a filesystem for my master's thesis.